# Criando arquivo XML Com Buscar um determinado usuario na tabela usando forEach jpa java

Tags: jpa

Bom dia !!

Pessoal minha duvida é a seguinte

tenho duas tabelas uma Pessoa e outra Funcionário.

estou fazendo um for nas duas tabelas para poder criar um arquivo Xml, porem como eu não estou retornado os resultados por Id e sim pela ordem do for,
meu xml esta sendo criado porem não está puxando os dados corretos.

o campo cargo está puxando o de outro funcionário conforme exemplo abaixo

**Errado**

2
    Rafael
    Analista de Sistema

**Certo**

2
    Rafael
    Editor

segue abaixo o código para criar o Xml

```
    // Gerando Arquivo Xml Para Exportação.
private File GerarXmlFuncionarios() {

    List<FuncionarioModel> funcionariosModel = funcionarioRepository.todos();

    List<PessoaModel> pessoasModel = pessoaRepository.todas();

    // Nome do Elemento Raiz do Xml
    Element elementDados = new Element("funcionarios");

    Document documentoFuncionarios = new Document(elementDados);

    funcionariosModel.forEach(funcionario -> {
        pessoasModel.forEach(pessoa -> {
            // Campos dos Xml com os Seus Valores
            Element elementFuncionario = new Element("funcionario");
            elementFuncionario.addContent(new Element("codigo").setText(pessoa.getCodigo().toString()));
            elementFuncionario.addContent(new Element("nome").setText(pessoa.getNome()));
            elementFuncionario.addContent(new Element("cargo").setText(funcionario.getCargo()));

            elementDados.addContent(elementFuncionario);
        });
    });

    XMLOutputter xmlGerado = new XMLOutputter();
    xmlGerado.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat().setEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));

    try {

        // Gera o Nome do Arquivo 
        String nomeArquivo = "funcionarios_".concat(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()).concat(".xml");

        // Caminho que o Arquivo Sera Salvo 
        File arquivo = new File("C:/Pasta/Sistema_Web/".concat(nomeArquivo));

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(arquivo);

        xmlGerado.output(documentoFuncionarios, fileWriter);

        return arquivo;

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Classes PessoaRepository e FuncionarioRepository onde eu retorno minha lista de ambas classes

```
    public List<PessoaModel> todas() {
    TypedQuery<PessoaModel> query = manager.createQuery("from PessoaModel", PessoaModel.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}


    public List<FuncionarioModel> todos() {
    TypedQuery<FuncionarioModel> query = manager.createQuery("from FuncionarioModel", FuncionarioModel.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

**segue solução abaixo**
    funcionariosModel.forEach(funcionario -> {
                    // Campos dos Xml com os Seus Valores
                    Element elementFuncionario = new Element("funcionario");
                    elementFuncionario.addContent(new Element("codigo").setText(funcionario.getPessoaModel().getCodigo().toString()));
                    elementFuncionario.addContent(new Element("nome").setText(funcionario.getPessoaModel().getNome()));
                    elementFuncionario.addContent(new Element("cargo").setText(funcionario.getCargo()));
                    elementDados.addContent(elementFuncionario);
        });

Comment: Me parece que o problema é no seu `pessoasModel.forEach` **dentro** do `funcionariosModel.forEach`. Você está percorrendo toda a lista de pessoas para cada funcionário. Qual é a relação entre funcionários e pessoa? Se houver uma relação, não seria melhor retorná-los em uma única consulta, já que do modo que você está fazendo, não há nenhuma garantia de que o funcionário esteja relacionado aquela pessoa especificamente.

Comment: Oi Felipe, primeiramente obrigado por responder.  sei que o meu problema é mesmo esse que vc mencionou, um forEach dentro de outro não me da o resultado esperado.   e dentro da minha tabela funcionário tenho o Id_pessoa que seria minha chave estrangeira da tabela pessoa, sei que o certo é fazer o uso dessa chave. e fazer somente um for de funcionário e retorna a pessoa pelo id mais não sei como poderia fazer isso. caso possa me ajudar fico grato

Comment: Pela resposta que você deu abaixo, parece que você já resolveu o problema. Para você compreender um pouco melhor como o relacionamento entre as entidades funciona dê uma olhada nesses dois links sobre [Lazy e Eager Load](http://blog.caelum.com.br/entendendo-o-lazy-e-o-eager-load-da-jpa/) e [Fetch Strategy](https://vladmihalcea.com/2013/10/17/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/).

Answer (score 0):

Já que não tem um controle efetivo de cada elemento, sugiro realizar sua consulta no banco de dados de forma ordenada (**`ORDER BY`**) para ter maior garantia de que os dados corretos caminhem em paralelo.

Segunda coisa é fazer essa interação com o forEach do Java 8, mas eu não sei como isso deverá ser feito, porém com uma interação com o tradicional for ficaria algo assim:

```
int funcionarioAdd = 0;
int pessoaAdd = 0;

for(List<FuncionarioModel> funcionario: funcionariosModel) {
 for(List<PessoaModel> pessoa: pessoasModel) {          
   if(funcionarioAdd == pessoaAdd++) {
    // Campos dos Xml com os Seus Valores
    Element elementFuncionario = new Element("funcionario");
    elementFuncionario.addContent(new Element("codigo").setText(pessoa.getCodigo()));
    elementFuncionario.addContent(new Element("nome").setText(pessoa.getNome()));
    elementFuncionario.addContent(new Element("cargo").setText(funcionario.getCargo()));
    elementDados.addContent(elementFuncionario);
    pessoaAdd = 0;
    break;
   }       
  }
 funcionarioAdd++;
}
```

Verifique a lógica corretamente e tome cuidado pois as chances de os dados perderem a ordenação é muito alta nesse tipo de procedimento (ordenar sem as chaves que garantem a consistência).

Answer (score 0):

Felipe e n3uRoQuiLa, Muito Obrigado mais uma vez pela ajuda  de vocês.

consegui resolver conforme abaixo, afinal estou trabalhando orientado a objeto era mais simples do que pensei.

```
        funcionariosModel.forEach(funcionario -> {
                // Campos dos Xml com os Seus Valores
                Element elementFuncionario = new Element("funcionario");
                elementFuncionario.addContent(new Element("codigo").setText(funcionario.getPessoaModel().getCodigo().toString()));
                elementFuncionario.addContent(new Element("nome").setText(funcionario.getPessoaModel().getNome()));
                elementFuncionario.addContent(new Element("cargo").setText(funcionario.getCargo()));
                elementDados.addContent(elementFuncionario);
    });
```

mais uma vez grato espero um dia poder retribuir